# Dúvida sobre script simples de criptografia em Python

Tags: python

Alguém pode me explicar oque exatamente essa linha faz, quando eu tento entender ela, acabo me enrolando mais ainda:

```
#Vars definidas: 

import sys

key = sys.argv[2]
mode = sys.argv[3]
posiçãoDoChar = 0 
xored = ''


for char in msg:
    xored += chr(ord(key[posiçãoDoChar%len(key)]) ^ ord(char)) # ESTÁ LINHA EXATAMENTE 
    posiçãoDoChar += 1

print(xored)
```

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.

Comment: @ArturBrasil - a pergunta está boa. Não está "perfeita"  - não tem como alguém chegando a primeira vez fazer uma pergunta "perfeita"  - mas tem uma dúvida bem descrita e respondível. Conselhos de melhoria e edições são coisas legais. Votos negativos e para fechar a questão não fazem sentido.

Answer (score 3):

A linha faz algumas chamadas de função e uma operação de "xor", usando o operador `^` - e concatena o resultado numa string que ele chama de "xored".

podemos desdobrar por partes para ficar mais fácil entender:

```
xored += chr(ord(key[posiçãoDoChar%len(key)]) ^ ord(char))
```

é o mesmo que:

```
posicao_da_letra_da_chave = posicaoDoChar % len(key)  
# O "modulo" - "%" é  o resto da divisão  -entao 
# se sua chave tem 4 letras, quando 
# estiver na letra "5", 5%4 vale 1: 
# a letra na posicao "1"  da chave é reutilizada, e assim por diante.
letra_da_chave = key[posicao_da_letra_da_chave]
codigo_numerico_da_letra_da_chave = ord(letra_da_chave)  # converte o caractere em seu código numérico UNICODE (se for um caractere ASCII, isso é equivalente ao código ASCII)
codigo_numerico_da_letra_da_mensagem = ord(char)
codigo_numerico_cifrado = codigo_numerico_da_letra_da_chave ^ codigo_numerico_da_letra_da_mensagem # Operação de transformação reversível usando 'xor'
nova_letra = chr(codigo_numerico_cifrado)
xored += nova_letra  # contatena a nova letra na mensagem cifrada final
```

Então, de fato, quando desdobramos, só aquela linha faz 8 operações distintas.

A chave do processo é o "xor", feito com o operador "^": isso é uma operação feita
bit a bit entre os dois valores: se *um* dos dois valores for "1" e o outro "0" o resultado é "1". Se os dois valores forem iguais, o resultado é "0". Essa operação tem uma propriedade interessante que ela é reversível: se eu faço um "xor" de um número X que eu tenho, com um número Y, o resultado é um número diferente "Z". Se eu faço xor de volta de Z com Y, o resultado é "X" - por isso que esse algoritmo consegue recuperar a mensagem original - na descriptografia, cada caractere cifrado vai sofre um xor com a mesma letra da chave com que foi "xorada" na operação de criptografar.

Aqui o XOR funcionando com variáveis numéricas:

```
In [10]: x = 43254                                                                                                                                                                                                

In [11]: y = 64636                                                                                                                                                                                                

In [12]: z = x ^ y                                                                                                                                                                                                

In [13]: z                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[13]: 21642

In [14]: y ^ z                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[14]: 43254

In [15]: y ^ z == x                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[15]: True
```

E, de novo, mas dessa vez usando o prefixo `0b` e a chamada `bin` para visualzar o processo vendo os números em binário:

```
In [16]: x = 0b11110000                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [17]: y = 0b10101010                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [18]: z = x ^ y                                                                                                                                                                                                

In [19]: bin(z)                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Out[19]: '0b1011010'

In [20]: bin(z ^ y)                                                                                                                                                                                               
Out[20]: '0b11110000'
```

Comment: Ainda tenho algumas dificuldades, até por quê a var vai receber uma info que foi processada por 8 métodos, mais ainda assim agora ficou mais claro o entendimento, negócio agora é praticar, muito obrigado mano, me ajudou mto...

Comment: Se conseguir entender como é que essas 8 operações estão naquela primeira linha, já vai dar pra entender bastante coisa - tente ler as descrições das operações que fiz do final para o começo - é mais ou menos como acontece naquela linha. Tipo "ah vou fazer o xor de um valor da mensagem original com um valor que veio da chave." "como eu pego esses valores? Ah - na linha de cima ele chama o "ord" " - e assim por diante.